# I chose the wrong job and the wrong place to work at

Tags: work-experience, work-life-balance

I feel like I might have chosen the wrong job. I love research, coming up with solutions, and creating things, and my field is in technology. However, after getting my phd I was burned out and a bit lost. and even though I have so many ideas that can be implemented and would sell in a minute, I just didn't know where to start (on my own) and if this is the right time to do it. Since I felt that I'm not ready to start on implementing my own ideas, I applied for an assistant prof job and I got it.

It turns out that the university I'm in is not that great. The management is terrible, and research isn't a priority. I wasn't given an introduction and there was no onboarding process. I was given multiple tasks (a lot of them outside of my job description) to do the moment I stepped in and was assigned courses to teach without giving me a choice (and it's outside of my expertise but I can teach it since it is BSc level). On top of that, I was asked to attend compulsory courses that adds up to 13 hours a week for 3 months. (I guess that's my introduction).

I'm still in my first month in this job, but I'm not happy with it. I'm usually a very energetic and positive person, but now I feel physically and emotionally exhausted and tired. The lack of energy is not just because of the tasks I have to do, but also because of the toxic environment. I can't even do research, because I'm too busy trying to finish other tasks.

I'm not sure what is the right thing to do now? Do I stay at least a year before I decide to leave? Do I start applying for new jobs and leave as soon as I get one? I'm kind of afraid of going to another university, because I may face the same issues? I'm worried that if I leave academia then I lost the chance to do research independently. Starting my own business now is still risky (even though this is my dream)

I don't know what to do, I need advice...

Comment: Hi @user52773, welcome to the The Workplace. I'm sorry you're having trouble with your new job. Some advice is that here at the The Workspace we're not very good at answering questions that are really broad. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Also we cant tell you what to do. That you have to decide yourself. If you have a goal want to achieve we can help with that

Comment: How long have you been working on this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I stay at least a year before I decide to leave?

**If you are not happy with your job I would not recommend keep doing it for a year**. You will only end up more burnt out.

If you want to stay at least a year because otherwise it won't look too good on your resume remember you can always opt to *drop out such job from your resume*, given it were not a good fit for both parts and you were just a short time.

> Do I start applying for new jobs and leave as soon as I get one? I'm kind of afraid of going to another university, because I may face the same issues?

Given the content and tone of your post, seems that indeed you should be searching for a new job.

If you *thoroughly check and consider* the options that are presented to you, you will be able to make sure the same issues won't happen again. Don't just take the first offer you get, and don't rely just on one.

Consider several options, check with your colleagues and contacts if they know about the culture and environment on such universities, check online and other sources on them, and finally make a choice and go for it.